# I getting an empty lists after intersect in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, intersect

I have 2 columns and in each column I have 5 words in each row.

For example:
x=[dog|cat|mouse|new|world]
y=[fish|cat|new|thing|nice]

And I need to find intersections between them [cat|new].

But it shows me an empty list. Do you know why?

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

intersect1=[]
    
for j in range(len(data)):
    #print('==========================================================================')
        x=str(data.iloc[:, 2]).split("|")
        y=str(data.iloc[:, 3]).split("|")  


        #get_jaccard_sim(x, y) 
    
        #intersect.append(result)


        intersect= list(set(x) & set(y))   
        intersect1.append(intersect)
    
#print(inter)
print(intersect1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in your iteration loop, you are selecting the whole column when you do `data.iloc[:,2]` when you want to only select each value row by row. Change the `:` to use the counter in your loop, `j`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['dog|cat|mouse|new|world'],
                   'y': ['fish|cat|new|thing|nice']})
  
for j in range(len(df)):
      x=str(df.iloc[j, 0]).split("|")
      y=str(df.iloc[j, 1]).split("|")
      intersect= list(set(x) & set(y))   

print(intersect)
```

Output:

```
['new', 'cat']
```

Comment: I get in this way empty lists also

Comment: You will need to share a more concrete dataset for us to look into. This above code worked well for me

Comment: I realized I took the wrong columns in excel that's why. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I just did a test using the code below:

```py
data1 = "dog|cat|mouse|new|world"
data2 = "fish|cat|new|thing|nice"

x = data1.split("|")
y = data2.split("|")

intersect= list(set(x) & set(y))

print(intersect)
```

This outputs `['cat', 'new']`, exactly what you'd expect. Note that `x` and `y` are arrays containing the words as separate strings, *i.e.*:

```py
['dog', 'cat', 'mouse', 'new', 'world'] # this is x
['fish', 'cat', 'new', 'thing', 'nice'] # this is y
```

Make sure that this is also the case in your code!

Answer (score 1):

Even though you added the code in a loop, you are not actually traversing your dataframe. Assuming your data is of this shape:

```
    one two
0   [dog|cat|mouse|new|world]   [fish|cat|new|thing|nice]
1   [dog|cat|mouse|new|world]   [fish|cat|new|thing|nice]
2   [dog|cat|mouse|new|world]   [fish|cat|new|thing|nice]
3   [dog|cat|mouse|new|world]   [fish|cat|new|thing|nice]
4   [dog|cat|mouse|new|world]   [fish|cat|new|thing|nice]
5   [dog|cat|mouse|new|world]   [fish|cat|new|thing|nice]
6   [dog|cat|mouse|new|world]   [fish|cat|new|thing|nice]
7   [dog|cat|mouse|new|world]   [fish|cat|new|thing|nice]
8   [dog|cat|mouse|new|world]   [fish|cat|new|thing|nice]
...
```

Then assuming the columns you're interested in are 2 and 3, modifying your like this would work:

```py
for j in range(len(data)):
    x = data.iloc[j, 2][0].split('|')
    y = data.iloc[j, 3][0].split('|')
    intersect = list(set(x) & set(y))
```